# Blur whole page (except two divs) works in fiddle but not standalone

Tags: css

I'm building a simple "tutorial / walkthrough" component for a single page app, a classic use case for "Blur everything except a couple of divs."  Following some excellent guides here, I spent far too many hours trying to make my app behave correctly before breaking it down to a minimum reproducible example using a code fiddle.

The linked fiddle does precisely the right thing, and it's exactly what many of you would have suggested:

- Establish some background body text that needs to be blurred.
- Build a couple of divs that are of class ".noblur" to highlight specific spots
- Apply a blur to "body > *:not(.noblur)" style.

Tragically, the code fiddle works PERFECTLY.  But when I apply the solution to my own SPA, it ... doesn't work.  Specifically:

- Everything is blurred, as if the ":not(selector)" hasn't selected anything to not blur.
- I've attempted to override this by applying the style "filter: blur(0rem);" to the .noblur components, but it doesn't work.
- The OverlayBox (which is of class noblur) ends up behind everything, as if it's had it's Z-index set very low.  Manually changing the z-index does not help.
- The other_box ends up with height 0, and Chrome's debug tells me that left, width, and height are invalid properties.

Obvious next step: Trim down my SPA to the minimum necessary to make it not work, then share that.  At first, I hacked out all of Bootstrap, and it seemed to work ... but then I couldn't reproduce that by adding BS to the JSFiddle.  So that's a false rabbit trail.

Here's what I've trimmed it down to -- HTML and CSS all in one spot.

The basic HTML (which works):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <h2>A row of text across the top, before the tutorial bit entirely.</h2>

  <div id="tutorial">
    <style>
      body > *:not(.noblur) { filter: blur(0.2rem);}
    </style>
    <div id="whole_tutorial" class="noblur" style="position: absolute; z-index: 20; width: 100%; height: 1000px; filter: blur(0rem);" >
      <div id="tutorial_box" class="noblur" style="width: 420px; border: 2px rgba(36, 85, 240, 0.83); color: blue; background: green; padding: 25px; position: absolute; left: 200; top: 120; z-index: 5; filter: blur(0rem);" >
        <div class="noblur" style="filter: blur(0rem);">Some text that should come out on top of all the rest of this.</div>
        <div class="noblur" style="position: absolute; left: 10px; bottom: 10px;" >Un-blurred in div</div>
      </div>
      <div id="highlightbox" style="position: absolute; top: 250px; left: 150;  width: 30; height: 30; border-radius: 15px; border: 2px red; z-index: 5;" class="noblur">highlight</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div style="z-index:-1;">Link to click and show the tutorial</div>
  
  <div style="background: lightblue; width: 500px; font-size: 25px;">A bunch of body content lorem ipsum I forget the rest blah blah just fill this all in with a wall of text that gets blurred anyways.  Shouldn't end up being visible blah blah more text blah blah blah text lorem opsum.</div>

</body>
</html>
```

As I understand it from my simple fiddle, the "blur everything in the body including all children, except those things with .noblur" should leave some bits un-blurred.  Instead, I get ... this.
[image]

Which bit of CSS knowledge am I missing that makes the fiddle work and my minimum reproducible example not?

https://jsfiddle.net/djmcmath/a40sj9t3/18/

Comment: It would be better if your code example demonstrated what does NOT work rather than what does.

Comment: Yeah, that's a fair critique.  I'll go tear this down and see if I can find a clean way to show what does and doesn't work.  Thanks.

Comment: Ok, so it wasn't BootStrap at all.  My bad.  Still don't know what it is, but at least it wasn't Bootstrap.

Comment: You're probably missing that similarly to how `display:none` hides whole element with all its descendants (regardless of descendants' `display` settings), `filter` property affects whole element with all the descendants and you cannot just "unblur" some of them. So your approach requires that you set class `.noblur` very carefully

Comment: That's helpful, and good to know.  I pulled all of the "filter: blur(0rem);" lines from elements of the ".noblur" class.  Result is the same, unfortunately.  Also tried only setting the ".noblur" class on one or two specific elements -- no change.  What other rules might I be missing?

Comment: ... Ok, after much experimentation, I've learned that I can apply ".noblur" successfully to any element OUTSIDE the div in which the blur style is created.  That's awkward, because it's specifically the stuff INSIDE that div that I want to be not blurred.  Trying to re-arrange my thinking so this works correctly.

Comment: I've set it up -- somewhat awkwardly, from an architectural standpoint -- so the blur effect is at the root level, and I can kind of get the right effect.  Except that the divs don't position correctly: Chrome says left/width/height are "invalid properties."  (Weirdly, top is valid.)  I am entirely out of my depth here.

Comment: `left: 200; top: 120;` you must specify units (px?) for non-zero values of `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` properties.

Comment: Oh, heavens.  That was obvious, thank you.  Still trying to unblur the right bits, but that's one thing fixed.